# How to allow cross domain request geckofx

Tags: c#, cross-domain, geckofx

I am creating an app that use `GeckoFX` as browser control. Now i want to allow this browser control to allow cross domain request. i tried to add custom observer shown below but not working

```
public class RequestObserver: BaseHttpModifyRequestObserver
    {
        protected override void ObserveRequest(HttpChannel channel)
        {
            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.SetResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*", true); //add allow header to response for all request
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding response header to each request
And added this observer to `ObserverService` but it still give cross domain request error.

```
 ObserverService.AddObserver(new RequestObserver());
```

Anyone have idea about how to get it working?